# Summation with square and absolute values

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am currently trying to implement a paper that have square and summation values in their formulas like this:

$$
x_{z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n{R_{z}(i, j)^2}}
$$

$$
x_{z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n{|R_{z_i}^1 - R_{z_i}^2|}
$$

I don't know if I should square first the numbers in the first formula after doing the summation or square them before.

Also I don't really know if in the second formula I should take the absolute value after the summation or before.

Im pretty lost, I have been struggling for days and I don't know what to do. Can somebody throw a little bit of light?

Comment: For the quadratic sum, square first, then add. For the second sum with absolute values, where is the dependence on the index $i$?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry, I have edited now. It should be the index of R^1 and R^2

Comment: The second *is* a sum of absolute values, so take absolute values and then add.